# How to hide svg with react-native-reanimted when height is collapsing

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to achieve an animation on blur and focus of `TextInput` with `react-native-reanimated`
when the keyboard is opening or dismissing, the height will collapse but the problem here is if we have an `SVG` inside `Animated.View` it will not collapse like text

[image: logo before collapsing]

[image: another pic after collapsing]

[code on expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmedhamed70/awkward-bacon)

any improvements on the code will be appreciated too

Comment: I just want to say that having an expo snack linked to the question is super amazing and makes it so much easier to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `overflow: 'hidden'` to your `logoContainer` style.
Tested on my device, I think it behaves the way you want it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but added `withTiming` to the onBlur and onFocus and it worked. Not to say that it wouldnt work without it but, I imagine the OP is using shared values because he wishes for these values to be animated

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/40tvGKX1S

Comment: @joaocout thank you for your time, it works fine with your solution

Comment: @PhantomSpooks, `withTiming` makes it a little bit laggy when it collapses